# From measurement and states analyzer powegui Matlab to workspace

Tags: matlab, simulink, workspace, measurement, powergui

In Simulink, How can i store data from the powergui measurement and states analyzer block to workspace.
I tried with the following command but I could just see the nodes and not the corresponding voltages and currents
sps = power_steadystate('filename')

Answer (score 0):

Have u try to use a `to workspace` block? This block lets u to stack data from a Simulink simulation/executable. Only you have to stablish the name of the file (.mat), size of data and Ts. [Here u have more information](https://es.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html)

I hope u find this good.

BR.